# Plot in a Jupyter notebook depending on a true/false checkbox

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, ipywidgets

I have an interactive notebook with a few widgets, that displays a plot (+other data) based on the information given by the widgets.  The plot is only displayed if a Checkbox is checked.

Everything works well except one thing: the Checkbox has a True value by default. When loading the notebook for the first time, it appears as clicked but the plot is not displayed -- if I interact with the widgets in any other way (either by re-clicking this checkbox twice, or by modifying some of the other widgets), then the plot is displayed.

Is there a way to have the plot displayed at the beginning without waiting for the user to interact?

Comment: Can you share your code, ideally a simplified example.

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating your checkbox with the False value

`cb = widgets.Checkbox(value=False)`

Then, once you have set up your observse, in the code, change the value of the checkbox to True, and this should trigger your code.

`cb.value = True`